# How do i get Spring Vault to trust a custom TLS chain provided as PEM

Tags: spring, spring-vault

I am currently using Spring Vault with TLS, which works fine. My problem is that I need to support a custom TLS chain to connect to a client's Vault instance. Using a jks is not an option, my only option is to use PEM files.

I've read that Spring Vault is able to use PEM files for its SSL configuration, but I can't figure out how ... :(

Answer (score 0):

Technically you need to customize underlining web client and provide custom `SslConfiguration` loading certificates from PEM files and creating truststore in runtime.

Looking at `VaultAutoConfiguration` you could provide custom [`ClientFactoryWrapper`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-vault/blob/6ed11fc60003b4109e3939fa569f3bedcd383f59/spring-cloud-vault-config/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/vault/config/VaultAutoConfiguration.java#L131) bean configured with your `SslConfiguration`.